# How can I match the following in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Dear StackOverflow Population,

I have been trying to get two simple things to work but I can't get but 1 of them to.

So I have nginx server block it looks like the following

```
server {

        listen 443 default;
        server_name secure.<domain>.com;

        if ($host = $server_name) {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://secure.<domain2>.com$request_uri?systpl=<template> permanent;

}
```

I have also tried since I know that IF is evil I have tried something like

```
return 301 https://secure.<domain2>.com$request_uri?systpl=<template>;
```

of course then I disable the if statement above, this works okay so when we goto

**https://secure.domain.com => https://secure.domain2.com/?systpl=template**

That works fine and when you enter a PHP ending such as

**https://secure.domain.com/cart.php => https://secure.domain2.com/cart.php?systpl=template**

This works both with IF and simple return, and I figure I need to get the other in a different server block or a statement but here is where the problem lies

Now if you goto

**https://secure.domain.com/cart.php?id=7 => https://secure.domain2.com/cart.php?id=7?systpl=template**

This of course doesn't work since it would have to be **&systpl** since it doesn't end with *.php*, how can I achieve this so it appends **&systpl** if it does not end with *.php* and ends with string and if not then append it with **?systpl** if it ends with *.php*

I hope someone knows how this is done because I have crawled the first 6 pages of google results with various search strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding arguments, you should probably avoid using `$request_uri` and use `$uri` and `$args` instead.

The `return` statement could be rewritten as:

```
return 301 https://example.com$uri?systpl=template&$args;
```

The `rewrite` directive appends arguments by default, so this should work:

```
rewrite ^ https://example.com$uri?systpl=template permanent;
```

But as it is identical to the `return` statement, the `return` statement is preferred. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: This worked perfectly now both

index.php?systpl=template and cart.php?id=7&systpl=template

works, Could you explain WHY this works what is the workings of using $uri and $args, I mean when i goto the link it still dos id=7 and then appends &systpl=template while if i go just ti index.php it appends ?systpl=template, exactly what I wanted but why

Comment: You were using `$request_uri` which is the originating URI including the `?` and query string if present. The `$uri` variable  does not include the `?` and query string, which means new arguments can be easily appended.

Comment: Well this is accepted, this saved my day! and a headache! Thank you very much Richard